# polynomial with rational coefficients

Tags: polynomials

Do you think that the following statement is true? Do you have any idea about the proof?

Let $\; f(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ be a polynomial. If $f(n) \in \mathbb{Z}$ for an infinite number of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$.

Comment: This question is better suited to math.stackexchange.com. MathOverflow is intended for questions about research level mathematics.

Comment: I agree with Jeremy. But a hint is to use the calculus of finite differences. The book Concrete Mathematics by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik should get you well along the way.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a nice way to do it via calculus of finite differences, but that feels like overkill to me.  If $f$ has degree $d$, then it's determined by its values at $d+1$ points, and polynomial interpolation preserves rationality.

Comment: @HenryCohn It's a simple induction on degree, using the fact that each function $\binom{x}{n}$ "integrates" to $\binom{x}{n+1}$ (Pascal's triangle).

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I see how to do this if $f(n)$ is an integer for all $n$, but how do you handle the case where this is true for some arbitrary infinite set?  (I may be missing something obvious.)

Comment: @HenryCohn Oh, sorry! I completely misread the post. In any case, your suggestion is a simple answer.